# getent passwd -s sss LOCALUSER shows local user

Tags: users, sssd, getent

### tl;dr

I want to easily and quickly tell if a user is local or domain (don't care which domain).

#### Environment

- freeipa-client-4.6.1-3.fc27.x86_64
- sssd-1.16.0-4.fc27.x86_64

### Full story

I am writing a userinfo.sh script that will show if a user is local, sssd, can ssh, and is permitted by sssd.

Currently I am doing the check for if the user is from the domain with the `getent passwd -s sss $USERNAME` command. But I ran into an issue where checking the sssd database returns a local user!

```
# getent passwd -s sss 'bgstack15-local'
bgstack15-local:x:1000:1000:bgstack15-local:/home/bgstack15-local:/bin/bash
```

Checking the contents of the database (cache) for sss shows sssd apparently caches all sorts of information about the local user.

```
# sudo su root -c 'strings /var/lib/sss/db/* | grep bgstack15-local' | sort | uniq
name=bgstack15-local@implicit_files,cn=groups,cn=ih
name=bgstack15-local@implicit_files,cn=groups,cn=implicit_files,cn=sysdb
name=bgstack15-local@implicit_files,cn=users,cn=implicit_files,cn=sysdb
[...output truncated]
```

I tried clearing the sssd cache overall, and just for the user. Neither made a difference.

```
# sss_cache -U
# sss_cache -u bgstack15-local
```

The user does show up as a local user, and I promise it is only a local user!

```
getent passwd -s files 'bgstack15-local'
bgstack15-local:x:1000:1000:bgstack15-local:/home/bgstack15-local:/bin/bash
```

The man pages for [getent(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getent) and [getpwent(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwent) don't help me understand what could be going on. [sssd(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sssd) shows me that sssd can cache local users, which actually goes against what I want! The nss section of [sssd.conf(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf) doesn't help, but maybe I didn't take enough time to read it. I'm a little stuck.

**My sssd.conf**

```
[domain/ipa.example.com]
id_provider = ipa
ipa_server = _srv_, dns1.ipa.example.com
ipa_domain = ipa.example.com
ipa_hostname = fc27c-01a.ipa.example.com
auth_provider = ipa
chpass_provider = ipa
access_provider = ipa
cache_credentials = True
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ipa/ca.crt
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, ssh, sudo
domains = ipa.example.com
[nss]
homedir_substring = /home
[pam]
[sudo]
[autofs]
[ssh]
[pac]
[ifp]
[secrets]
[session_recording]
```

### Last resort

I can try doing my checks against `${USERNAME}@${DOMAIN}` when doing the `-s sss` check, but that means I then have to iterate over all domains in sssd.conf and that would slow the process down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option that controls this behavior is buried in sssd.conf(5) on CentOS 7 and Fedora, but not in the online man page.

**sssd.conf**

```
[sssd]
enable_files_domain = false
```

Reference 3 shows that sssd makes a "fast cache for local users."

From man sssd.conf(5) on my Fedora system:

> ```
>    enable_files_domain (boolean)
>        When this option is enabled, SSSD prepends an implicit domain with
>        “id_provider=files” before any explicitly configured domains.
>
>        Default: true
> ```

Disabling this behavior lets me make a simple check to see if it is a local user or domain user.

## References

1. ddg: [sssd disable caching local users](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sssd%20disable%20caching%20local%20users&t=ffab&ia=web)
2. [https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1357418](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1357418#14)
3. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SSSDCacheForLocalUsers
4. Fedora 27 sssd.conf(5)
5. https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2018/02/23/getent-passwd-s-sss-localuser-shows-local-user/